# Debian 9.13 Vino remote desktop gets black screen when machine boot with no monitor connected

Tags: debian, remote-desktop

I was running debian 9.13 with gnome GUI on a x86 (atom E3950) computer. If I connect the machine with a HDMI monitor, and try to access its remote desktop vino-server, everything is ok. but if the machine boots without any monitor connected to it and let a windows VNC viewer to access the Vino remote desktop server, all you can see is a black screen. BTW, if a gnome-terminal is started when booting, it could be seen.

[image]

could any one help me to analyze the problem and solve this issue.

Comment: Could you please clean up the question a little bit? It's a bit hard to understand what is expected to happen. Also, what have you done so far to try to solve it? What steps?

Comment: what 's expected to happen:  Vino should work correctly  even without a HDMI monitor connected.